# How to implement a xor gate with nand gates

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I try to resolve a problem, how to implement a xor gate with nand's gate.

A xor B = A'*B + A*B'

So, this becomes :

A xor B = A'*B + A*B' + A*A' + B*B' = A(A' + B') + B(A' + B') = (A + B)(A' + B') =

(with De Morgan apllied on the second term)  = (A + B)(AB)' = ..... ?

In this point i am blocked.
If someone can help me, please.
Thank you.

Comment: apply Demorgans law on first term as well.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a good start. Just re-distribute the second term over the first:

(A + B)(AB)' = A(AB)' + B(AB)'

And then apply De Morgan to the whole thing:

A(AB)' + B(AB)' = ((A(AB)')'(B(AB)')')'

The Boolean expression gets to be a little hard to read, but it translates to the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm08Fg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the exact same network works if all of the NAND gates are changed to NOR gates, except that you get an XNOR gate — the output is high if the inputs are equal.

Comment: Or maybe he could just use demorgans on (a + b) to give ( a'.b')', right where he left..?

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler: How exactly does that help? Now you're left with creating `A'` and `B'`, which requires two more inverters.

Comment: Right. It only "Looks"  simpler. As they say 'All that glitters isnt gold'. My apologies.